# Load-Time Dynamic Linking in C DLL Dirctroy

Tags: c, dll

I am using a DLL with load-time dynamic linking. I want to know how my executable know where the DLL file is without calling `LoadLibrary()` function which is run-time linking.
Does DLL has to be in same directory with the executable that load it with load-time linking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 The directory where the executable module for the current process is located.
2 The current directory.
3 The Windows system directory. The GetSystemDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
4 The Windows directory. The GetWindowsDirectory function retrieves the path of this directory.
5 The directories listed in the PATH environment variable.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx